# How can I make it clear to other road users that I'm an inexperienced cyclist?

Tags: safety, learning

I'm in my mid-20s and I'm currently learning to bike, on my own, as I don't have anyone to teach me. My goal is to be able to commute to work when I want to, be able to travel to nearby towns, and more generally to get over the frustration of not knowing how to bike.

Practicing turns, signals, maneuvering and the like on an empty parking lot is one thing, but I figured if I wanted to do the above, I'd have to actually get on the road at some point, so I've begun biking in the city. I had no extremely close calls so far, but I'm occasionally given "weird" looks by other road users, or honked at. When it's cyclists or pedestrians, I explain that I'm currently learning and ask them what I did wrong; folks are usually receptive ("we've all started somewhere!") and describe what I shouldn't have done, what I did by the book but they didn't expect me to, etc.

However, I can't stop motorists, and shouting "SORRY I'M NEW TO THIS" is unlikely to be heard, and more likely to be misheard as an insult. I have no way of knowing whether I was honked at because I was doing something dangerous, or the driver was just annoyed by me biking slowly, as my current average speed is about 10 km/h (6 mph). At the same time, the driver has no way of knowing whether I'm a cyclist unconcerned by road rules, or just an inexperienced one: people will make the natural (but wrong) assumption than mid-20s me being on a bike means I know what I'm doing.

**I'd like to have something to make it blatant to other road users that I'm a newbie.** My goal here is twofold:

- Motorists being a bit more cautious around me (though they should be to begin with, since as a cyclist I'm more vulnerable than they are)
- Not harming the cyclist community by having people think stuff like "cyclists are jerks who behave like they own the place, just look at this one".

Since I'm mostly thinking of high-speed users here, it should be something that can be seen and acknowledged in a second or so. For instance, in my country, young drivers (driving license obtained less than 3 years ago) have to stick an "A-disk" to their trunk:

[image: Back of a city car with a magnetic A-disk: red A in a white circle]

I've thought of patching one up with a white cloth and red marker, but I'm not sure it's the best thing to do:

- I'm not sure how I could make it stay on my backpack;
- I have very long hair (it reaches the middle of my butt), which I have trouble keeping tucked under a jacket while biking. I'm afraid my hair may hide the A-disk;
- I've never seen a cyclist with one, so I'm not sure motorists would understand it's a serious thing and not some kind of accessory.

**What else could I use, or how could I improve the A-disk idea?**

Some precisions, if relevant:

- Location is a French city with more than 30k inhabitants. From my inexperienced cyclist's point of view, it has a decent amount of bike paths and bike lanes, and the car drivers seem pretty patient (compared to the "cyclist nightmare situation" I've heard of in the biggest cities like Paris, Marseille, etc). I'm careful of taking the routes I've judged to be the most cyclist-friendly, but there are still cars (i.e. danger) on them.
- I have a helmet, a bell, a (weak) front light, a pump, side and back reflectors. I am thinking of buying a rear light and a high-visibility jacket.
- I can signal but only with my left hand.
- I can't bike while standing up on the pedals (yet).
- I don't have anyone to ride with me, and I can't attend the biking lessons given in my city (I'm at work when they take place).

---

I've searched this site for `beginner signal`, `inexperienced`, without success; and Googling variations of this question's title only bring up results about learning to bike as an adult, what to think of when biking in the city, etc, not this specific point about "beware the newb" signalling.

Comment: Perhaps a flag pole (with flag, perhaps with the "A"-logo on it), as people might associate those with kids bikes, who are learners too. Depending on your local laws, a rear light might be mandatory anyways. High-Vis jacket and always riding with lights on is a good idea IMO.

Comment: Try to join a critical mass, if any, or try to do short bicycle tours in the city on Sunday/Saturday early morning ... almost no cars, even the trottoir should be free, but sunlight and decent temperature ... you will be more confident in your bike skills.

Comment: Yeah, I guess we don't have an `inexperienced` tag around here: The active people on this site are usually the long-years-enthusiasts. Myself included (I've been biking for about 87% of my life, I simply don't remember being a beginner). Sorry that we probably can't really relate to what you are experiencing right now.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I meant I searched for the keyword, not the tag (would have written it in square brakcets otherwise). No worries though, there's already useful info in the comments and answers - plus, hey if newbie bikers ever have to come to the site, gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: I guess you should try to get *comfortable* with your bike before to start doing serious kilometers in traffic. Traffic is an enormously complex and chaotic thing, and you need to have your full attention on it when you enter it. It won't do if you are still distracted by things like balance while signalling or looking over your shoulder. I'd strongly recommend finding some traffic free paths to practice. It will also help if you get faster than 10km/h: Speed stabilizes your bike. Going at only 10km/h does not feel safe to me...

Comment: I wouldn't worry about Not harming the cyclist community by having people think stuff like "cyclists are jerks who behave like they own the place, just look at this one".  Unfortunately, there are far more jerks in the cyclist community for one more to make a difference.  Do the best you can to keep yourself safe and not badly inconvenience drivers and you are way ahead of the game.

Comment: Do you have the opportunity to ride with other cyclists, to learn and expand your skills ?

Comment: Two questions: do you know how to drive? What about simply making a big sign saying “SORRY, NEW CYCLIST” and attaching it to your bike or backpack?

Comment: @Criggie no, like I said the biking lessons take place when I work. There's no critical mass I'm aware of in my area (and with the Covid situation there's probably even less), and while periodically asking for advice is a thing, I'd be extremely uneasy asking someone who doesn't know me to ride with them: what if something happens to me and they feel guilty? It would be different if I could ask friends or family, but none of them is even remotely close to my city.

Comment: @MaplePanda no, I can't drive. I don't even officially have the theory test; currently working on it, mostly by dismounting often and Googling if what I want to do is legal, walking being the default option, and quite frankly I've learned much more that way that sitting in front of a computer doing repetitive quizzes. It _is_ risky, but I reckon I know enough (and get better with time) to bike in the city. Carefully, on low-traffic hours and nice weather, but I'll never get experience otherwise - plus, I found out that biking is the only thing that really takes my mind off things these days.

Comment: @MaplePanda while the idea is simple enough, I'm not sure a written sign is something that could be seen, read, and acknowledged in 1-2 seconds by a car driver going to 50 km/h (30mph)? But then again, not​ being a driver maybe I just don't realise it's actually easy to read. I was just wondering if there were any more "visual" standards for this, such as a biking A-disk.

Comment: @Jenayah I agree, learning from mistakes is often very effective, but you can't really make mistakes while riding in traffic. I would definitely recommend having a solid base knowledge of rules of the road, there are many situations you simply can't pull over and research about. As for the sign, as long as it's a decent size (30cm square?), any driver moving at a speed you need to be worried about will be able to read it.

Comment: I'm not a cyclist so thought my opinion might be useful since, presumably, everyone else here is. I made an account just so I could post this: There's probably nothing you can do to *imply* to me that you are a newbie. For example, I would not interpret  a flag with as anything special but I am also from a country where new drivers put a "New Driver" sign on the car, rather than an A. If I was, I am not certain that it would cross my mind that a common symbol like "A" might mean anything special if it weren't on a car. You would need a readable sign actually saying "New Driver".

Comment: @nobody Its a fair point and helps OP.

Comment: Ride like you are invisible.

Comment: I would definitely learn to signal with both hands before you go out in traffic again. And tie up your hair; it gets dirty and snarled in all that traffic, and in wind it can swirl into your face. Persevere, you will gain a bit of assurance, the other drivers can tell.

Comment: In France, bikes are frequently sold with almost useless lights. (In fact, in some other countries some French bicycle makers are legally forced to *remove* the lights that would come standard in France...) Please, don't ride with those lights after dusk. It's not safe. Get a quality light.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the French equivalent of The Highway Code? I think it is called the "code de la route". If you read all of it then you will know how car drivers are supposed to behave: know your enemy.

Comment: Hang an "L" plate on the back of your bike.

Comment: Find a local group of casual bike riders and ride short rides with them.  Let them know you are a new rider, and hang out near the tail of the group.  Watch what they do and ask them questions; after a few hours you'll gain lots of insight, and you'll have their knowledge and support to draw upon whenever you need it.

Answer (score 43):

This is an interesting and thoughtful question, and just the fact that you are thinking carefully about how other road users think about you is very valuable and will contribute to your safety on the road.

Your question makes a lot of sense. How do you indicate to drivers that you need and deserve their consideration and patience, especially when you have doubts about your own skill on the bike and the road right now?

Unfortunately, I am not sure that being seen as *inexperienced* will result in drivers being more considerate. I think it is likely to have the opposite effect. Just look how impatient and inconsiderate drivers can be when dealing with a learner driver who holds them up or inconveniences them.

Even children, unfortunately, don't in my experience get treated with more patience or consideration.

My warning would be that **making your inexperience clear to other drivers is likely to have negative results**.

## Three points

Instead, I believe that the key things are to be:

- **noticed** - the driver has to *see you* in the first place
- **thought about** - can you give the driver reasons to *think more carefully about you*?
- **respected** - can you give the driver reasons to *consider your value and needs*?

One of the best things I've read to help think about this is [David Martin's Theory of Big](https://www.tibsnjoan.co.uk/Big.html). I won't repeat its points here, but I think it's well worth reading.

Regarding those points above:

## To be noticed

Are you brightly lit, visible, do you stand out, catch eyes? Do you ride in a visible position, make clear, large signals? How do you dress, and move?

Mostly, these are easy things to do. Riding in a visible position needs confidence though; that's not always so easy.

## To be thought about

It's not enough merely to be *noticed*. You want to *take up some space in the thoughts of drivers*. What can you do to achieve this?

Unfortunately, once again it often does take some confidence to ride in a way that helps you get thought about.

For example, on a road that I know has pot-holes or gravel in awkward places, I will ostentatiously signal and move widely around them; this can help a driver think "oh, this person moves around and does stuff" (not: "I can slip by this cyclist without a moment's thought or without leaving much room").

If you need to signal, signal in big, clear, impossible-to-miss ways that look like they express meaning. What you signal are your *intentions*. The physical act of signalling will get you noticed, but *the expression of your intention is what will get you thought about*.

More: at a traffic light on a busy road, if I am stopped in front of a car, I might pretend to fiddle with a brake or pedal or gear, or tug at the strap of a pannier, just to occupy some attention of a driver while we wait for the lights to change (when? sometimes I just get a feeling that this might be a useful thing to do).

Or, if I spot an on-coming car on a narrow country lane, I will make sure to move clearly *across* the line of sight of the oncoming driver before slipping in to the side of the road to make room. I don't disappear into a hedge *before* the driver has seen me.

Generally, *you want to ride in ways that are cautious and predictable* but *without appearing to be* too predictable. If a driver is sure that they know what you will do, that can be very dangerous. Better that they are never entirely sure what you *will* do, so that they stay alert for what you *actually* do.

I try to *look* as though I might do something that needs them to respond to appropriately. I want them to *imagine* that the wheels *might* suddenly fall off my bike, that my bags *might* burst open strewing shopping in their path, that I *might* suddenly stop to admire a flower or greet a friend.

It's important to note: I am **absolutely not recommending foolish or dangerous behaviour.** Weaving around unnecessarily around other road users is dangerous. Doing unpredictable things is dangerous. Riding on unreliable equipment can be dangerous. Actually having a loose bag is dangerous.

There are two more important ways that help you get thought about. They are to:

### Make strong, clear eye-contact

Eye-contact is valuable. You exchange a lot of information - for example, you can communicate an intention - but you also simply place yourself in another's thoughts by it.

### Avoid eye-contact

Sometimes, the opposite is called for. If a driver thinks you haven't seen them, they will be thinking about you and wondering what you will do. That's exactly what you want. So sometimes, I studiously avoid catching a driver's eye.

Which of these two techniques you adopt in any particular case will depend on the precise circumstances; I'm not sure I could formulate a clear rule. Both require and demonstrate a kind of confidence.

But either way, you don't want to appear as an uncertain, diffident road-user whose intentions and future actions are of no consequence and don't need to be thought about.

## To be respected

Finally, you need to be respected. There are two senses to being respected:

### You need to be respected as a human being

People, mostly, will recognise and respect another's humanity. Show that you are a human being, a being like them, to whom they have a duty of care.

The acts described earlier that help you get thought about flow directly into this. Now, as well as being thought about as a road user or as another vehicle on the road, you want to take another step, to be thought about *as a human being*.

**So do human things, and look human.**

I might take my hat off (I don't bother wearing a helmet, but it's not a discussion I'm much interested in having) and scratch my head on a long downhill stretch. "Oh," thinks the driver, recognising that I am a person just like them, "that person has an itch." Or I will tuck my top in, or pull it out. I might blow my nose at the traffic lights. Something that shows that I have a human body will never be to my disadvantage.

I'm not suggesting to make your bike rides into an unrelenting pantomime of extravagant gestures and unnecessary actions. You don't need to put on any kind of absurd performance (which in itself would be dangerous). It's rather that what you do, when you do it and who you do it in front of makes a difference, so you need to think about it, and use it to your advantage.

### You need to be respected as a respectable road user

As well as automatically deserving respect as a human being, which you'd hope would be recognised by all, it also helps to *earn* respect. Maybe this shouldn't be necessary, but unfortunately, it often is.

Ride politely and considerately. Obey the rules of the road, and make a point of doing so. Stop at lights. Courteously invite motorists to pull out or pass when it's safe to do so.

If a driver makes way for you, make it clear that you thank them. Don't just wait to notice it, *try to catch drivers in the act of being considerate* so that you can acknowledge it.

Finally, people often respect people who behave as though they deserve respect. That is a good way to ride: confidently, as though you belong on the roads, as though you expect their consideration and respect. Diffidence and uncertainty will unfortunately lose you that respect from some drivers. Act confidently - such as making signals and decisions - even when you don't feel like it, or at least, as much as you can.

This is why I think that advertising your inexperience can do you more harm than good.

It's really hard to do many of the things that I have advocated above. They take confidence, and experience, and practice. Many of them involve demonstrating your vulnerability as a road user, but not your weakness.

I hope this helps, and I hope it helps think about how you need to appear in the eyes of other road users.

I wish I could offer more useful advice about how to do this, for a person who doesn't know already how to. In the meantime, I hope you enjoy your riding and acquire the confidence you're looking for.

Comment: Train on car-free places like empty car parks or bicycle-legal but otherwise car-free streets. Or join a local cycling club as they often provide training for beginners in a safe environment.

Comment: Note that some actual studies have shown that drivers give less space to cyclists on high-end road bikes (in lycra) than cyclists in regular clothes riding cruiser-style bikes.

Comment: This is a great answer.  You should not expect more room as a newbie.  You should be looking to get "up to speed" as quickly as possible.  One part of that is controlling the bike.  You want to ride predictably, not swerve out into the road because you need to do that to avoid falling.  The other part is anticipating what the cars are going to do.  They do crazy things at times, and if it is into you it is a big problem.  Usually they give indications of it.  For example, a quick right turn is a danger but usually they will slow down and drift right.  Learn what to watch for.

Comment: I also use these two eye contact techniques, experience teaches you which is appropriate at the time 

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot of useful information in there :) _", try to catch drivers in the act of being considerate"_ this especially, I realised I probably missed such situations by being otherwise focused on, well, not falling/getting doored/crashing into someone etc. I guess "get tougher" is not the answer I'd have wanted (I though someone may post a creative DIY thingy, maybe someone will, who knows?), but is probably the down-to-earth answer :/ as per my second goal though, I'll have to appear confident without giving the false impression that the cyclist community is cocky, I guess...

Comment: @Jenayah I hope I didn't give the impression of advising to "get tougher". When you go to the bakery, you know all the rules. You hold the door for the old lady on the way out, you wait patiently in line, you say "Bonjour Madame" when it's your turn, you know what you want in advance, you have the money ready, etc. You are prepared, polite, clear about what you want and make it easy for everyone to accommodate your needs. At the bakery, you are confident - not tough. But it can take some resilience on the roads, especially if you encounter set-backs.

Comment: @LamarLatrell The OP said the location was France. I remember some advice I got before driving a car for the first time in France: "Making metal-to-metal contact with another car is not a big deal, but *never* make eye-to-eye contact with the driver unless you want to start a fight or have a race."

Comment: _"I am not sure that being seen as inexperienced will result in drivers being more considerate. I think it is likely to have the opposite effect."_ -- nope. Study after study shows that drivers are much more respectful of, and careful around, riders who appear "less professional". This mainly boils down to gender and dress. If you look like a male, and/or you are in cycling-specific gear (especially a helmet, unfortunately), drivers will pass more closely and act more dangerously than if you look like a female (including simply having long hair) and/or are wearing street clothes.

Comment: That said, there is some disagreement in the science. E.g. https://www.bicycling.com/news/a25358099/drivers-give-helmet-cyclists-less-room/ vs. https://genderpolicyreport.umn.edu/bicycles-gender-and-risk/

Comment: @PeterDuniho "Less professional" is nothing to do with being "inexperienced". It's a fairly well-established effect that the male helmeted rider wearing matching clothes on a new racing bike seems to attract - through no fault of their own - inconsiderate and dangerous behaviour from drivers. But "looking professional" is nothing to do with being and looking experienced and confident. Meanwhile, the diffident, uncertain, indecisive, wobbly beginner definitely does get less respect and consideration, even though they need it the most.

Comment: @DanieleProcida: _""looking professional" is nothing to do with being and looking experienced and confident."_ -- true, but not relevant. The point here is how _motorists_ perceive cyclists, and how that perception affects their behavior.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I completely disagree with you, because I have seen no evidence whatsoever that drivers are more respectful and considerate of diffident, inexperienced road users, including cyclists, than confident, experienced ones, and vast amounts of evidence to the contrary.

Comment: I agree with every one of the recommendations here, even though many of them are contradictory and knowing which one to use when only comes with experience. Unfortunately, there are so many distracted, inconsiderate drivers who aren't paying much attention at all, that there is no guarantee that any of these will help. The comment "ride like you're invisible" is the most true statement I've seen. Despite riding in _very_ bright clothing, I've had many people pull out right in front of me, never having seen me.

Comment: @Daniele: _"...and vast amounts of evidence to the contrary"_ -- such as? My evidence comes from cited studies, as well as my own personal experience, verified by analysis of video captured by the front- and rear-facing cameras that are running every time I'm on the road, commuting to work every day. The most promising result is that far more drivers are cautious around a cyclist than not (though it takes only one bad driver to ruin one's day), and especially that I see drivers are much more cautious around me when I have my family with me than when I'm alone. YMMV.

Comment: "making your inexperience clear to other drivers is likely to have negative results" Yes, basically it's trying to fix the wrong problem. Don't bother.

Comment: This is such an excellent, well thought out answer, and I agree with everything. I would say that I generally err on the no-eye-contact side: my experience is that other people will interpret some intention from eye-contact, whether I'm trying to communicate it or not, and I have very mixed results as to whether it's the right one. I think it's safer not to give any intention if there's a good chance it'll be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 19):

Cars drivers are not going to give you any breaks because you are new at cycling, so you need to learn how to not be a newbie.

If you have trouble controlling the bike you need to go somewhere safe and practice. Ride on grass if you think you may fall off. Practice stopping. starting, signaling, taking either hand off the bars to signal, looking over you shoulder to get a good look for cars behind on both sides, executing emergency stops and tight turns etc. Standing up on the pedals or going faster are not required, but being able to lift your butt off the saddle a little to cushion the jolt of going over bumps is a very useful skill for comfort and to keep control.

Learn the rules and laws of the road where you live. Find out what you are expected or required to do as a cyclist.

Learn defensive cycling techniques. These involve positioning on the road, predicting what car drivers will do, finding safe ways through intersection etc. use Strava, Google maps, Komoot or other routing apps to find the most bike friendly routes.

You may not have cycling fiends to teach you but there’s a lot to be learnt online. YouTube especially is a great resource.

Comment: Be prepared to apply some common sense to what you see on YouTube... My kids took a cycling class in their local 4-H club and some of the stuff they taught them there was absolute rubbish!

Comment: I think this is the best answer... just get better and more confident at riding - there is no substitute for that.

Answer (score 18):

Around here the most highly-correlated sign of a new cyclist is a high-visibility vest:

[image: High visibilty yellow vest]

They're not expensive (a [search on Amazon UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/slp/hi-visibility-vest/rejm6rkf2edm9wg) pulls up several under £5),  lightweight enough to not be hugely uncomfortable in the summer, and loose enough to go over a light jacket in cooler weather.

Comment: I've never heard that wearing hi-vis is correlated with being a new cyclist.  Personally I started wearing them (in winter) 20 years after learning to ride a bike.  Are you sure this is correlated?  Also: no need to buy this on Amazon, you may well find it in a large supermarket (certainly in a hypermarché), building supplies store, or well-stocked bike shop that needs your support (in particular in those difficult times).

Comment: +1 In Bulgaria this is mandated by law. Furthermore, numerous well-intended drivers have told me "please wear one of those. I can NOT see you when traveling at 100km/h even in broad daylight."

Comment: Or there are a lot of very experienced touring cyclists in your region.

Comment: I guess it would be too much to require drivers to not be blind. I know I have better than average eyesight, but the idea of not seeing a cyclist because they're driving 100 km/h sounds completely outlandish to me.

Comment: It's a good advice to wear one for security reasons, BUT it's not true that it's for new cyclists. Even more: saying this might induce some people to not wear it, in order to not look like a newbie, which is not good at all. I'm an experienced cyclist and I'd like to stay crash-free so I always wear one.

Answer (score 12):

That's a good question, and is great that you are taking the time to think about these issues. You have stated your goals clearly, so I am going to address those rather than your specific questions, since, as I will try to explain, I don't think your goals are best met in the way you are now imagining.

You say you want

> Motorists being a bit more cautious around me (though they should be to begin with, since as a cyclist I'm more vulnerable than they are)

> Not harming the cyclist community by having people think stuff like "cyclists are jerks who behave like they own the place, just look at this one".

Drivers knowing that you are inexperienced will *not* make them more cautious or considerate around you: [Walker et al. 2014](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001457513004636) (the paper is sadly paywalled, but one of the scenarios they tested was a hi viz jacket with a prominent "novice cyclist" sign on it; this did not lead to wider overtaking space).

This is in line with my personal experience - cycling "cautiously" is more likely to attract frustration than consideration. Drivers are more likely to employ "usurping" behaviour (things that are illegal and dangerous to cyclists but avoid an inconvenience to the driver) if they think they can intimidate you into, for example, yielding to them even if you have right of way.

Slightly tongue in cheek, your long hair may be your best bet. The same author [Walker 2007](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001457506001540) found that drivers *did* leave him extra space if he wore a long wig. This comes from a place of patronising sexism but, if it helps you keep safe, go for it. My hair doesn't grow long, but I cycle in dresses a lot and I have the impression that it helps (I do end up showing a fair bit of leg, so there's also that).

I cannot speak for the cycling community as a whole, but my position is that you should not worry *at all* about the second point. As long as you follow the law (no riding on pavements, unless it's legal where you are, no running red lights etc) you have the same rights to the road as anyone else. There's a subset of the driving community that does not agree with this, and will consider *all* cyclists on the road as an inconvenience and an imposition. Nothing you can do will change their mind. Unfortunately these people are the most likely to cause you trouble. You will develop a sense for them over time. I fully acknowledge that this will be inflammatory and contested, but I am extra wary of professional drivers (taxis and delivery, buses depending on road design), drivers of oversized urban suvs and similar "macho" vehicles, and of course erratic/bad/reckless drivers.

There are a couple of things in your post that could be improved, in particular

- do learn to signal with both hands. In France, the right hand will be less important but you still need it in roundabouts (which can be very unpleasant on a bike) and in general you want to be confident enough to be able to take either hand off the bike in an emergency (ask me about wasps!).
- some emergency braking practice in a parking lot will never go amiss - mostly so that you do it without having to think.
- get good lights front and back, probably the detachable type if you expect to leave the bike in public places. I would go so far as to recommend a main detachable set (I use usb rechargeable led lights) and a cheap backup set permanently attached for when your main run out of batteries/are in the other bag/you didn't expect to stay so late and now it's dark.
- you don't necessarily need to know how to fix your bike, but you need to be able to tell when it needs fixing and have someone who can do it for you. This is particularly important re: brakes.

More broadly

- Really look into defensive cycling techniques. They are very much not what you may imagine. Others have mentioned a lot of good tips on positioning, eye contact etc, and see also [this article](https://www.edinburghbicycle.com/info/what-is-defensive-cycling/). The core of defensive cycling is never to put the driver in a position to choose between your safety and their convenience: sometimes, this means specifically reducing their convenience (e.g. cycling in the middle of the road, or "taking the lane", so that they can't overtake you by squashing you to the side). Please use normal road user courtesy where you can (and acknowledge it when others do it for you) but never to the detriment of your safety.
- Do not try too much to make drivers "care" for you. The most dangerous drivers are those who will never care about a cyclist anyway. You can't know which those are, so the safe and sensible position is to assume that each driver is a bloodthirsty incompetent cnut. This is obviously unfair in most drivers' case, but they will never know, and will keep you alive in the small proportion of cases when you turn out to be correct.

And remember: you gain more years of good, healthy life with the cardiovascular benefits of cycling than you risk (on average) in an accident!

Comment: As much as I would like the last paragraph to be true: source? I doubt it is true. Unless you consider two groups of which one spends a given amount of time on the bike, the other the same amount of time eating processed pork...

Comment: According to [this study](https://www.newscientist.com/article/2237214-why-the-health-benefits-of-cycling-to-work-outweigh-the-risk-of-injury/), the mortality of bicycle-commuters is lower than that of car or public transit commuters, even though the risk of injury is higher, just because of the health benefits of physical activity.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.bmj.com/content/368/bmj.m336 Relevant quote: "Commuters who cycled to work had a lower risk of cardiovascular disease, cancer, and death than those who did not." Edit: my ref is the paper that Erlkoenig's article is based on. Great minds, etc

Comment: Very true statements! The "overly cautious motorist" is just as frustrating to other drivers as the "overly cautious cyclist" is. "Taking the lane" especially at a traffic light or stop sign can be vital to keeping you from getting squashed by someone turning right who wouldn't have otherwise seen you. It also prevents you from being the idiot zipping up the shoulder past all the stopped drivers, impatiently waiting their turn and getting annoyed by the "idiot cyclist who can't wait his turn".

Comment: @Erlkoenig It's important to note that the conclusion in the paper is not scientific, since the bicycling/non-cycling groups are self-selected and those in poorer health are more likely to choose to be in the non-cycling group. That makes cycling or not an effect rather than a cause.

Comment: The paper is a retrospective observational study, that is a far cry from "not scientific" - it would be impossible do a 20 year RCT on a lifestyle choice. You can perhaps argue about their comparators or the representativeness of Biobank participants, but it's disingenuous to suggest that the authors are unaware of the problem you suggest: "Cox models were adjusted first for age and sex, then additionally for ethnicity, Townsend deprivation index score, comorbidities [..] BMI, smoking [..] alcohol drinker status [..] and five levels of physical activity."

Answer (score 10):

In The Netherlands kids have an orange flag attached to their bike making the young, vulnerable (and inexperienced) biker more noticeable and signaling that the there's a vulnerable road user present:

[image]
<sub>(Sorry, I couldn't find another photo of the flag so I used this photo of a kid. No offence meant w.r.t. your biking abilities)</sub>

The flag "pole" is flexible and by its wobbly movement attracts more attention to the flag. Perhaps you can attach such a flag with the letter A on it to signal you're a new biker?

As noted in the comments, recumbent bicycles also use these in NL, so it's not only for young/inexperienced riders.

<sub>Apparently [Erlkoenig](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/44641/erlkoenig) already noted this idea in [a comment](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/69375/how-can-i-make-it-clear-to-other-road-users-that-im-an-inexperienced-cyclist/69423?noredirect=1#comment159008_69375), but I only saw that comment *after* I posted this answer.</sub>

Comment: In the US those are also often used on kids' bikes _and_ on recumbents. I always presumed they were simply to add visibility as the target they're attached to is smaller, compared to an adult on a traditional bike. Very few recumbent riders I've encountered are rookies, except, maybe, to the recumbent - most are experienced riders who've transitioned to the new position.

Comment: Yes, here recumbents also use those flags, that's true. I might've been over-assuming the link between a flag and low skill. Perhaps it's more about signaling vulnerability w.r.t. other traffic. Regardless, I think that flag + sticking an `A` on it (or whatever symbol is used to indicate a new driver) is a clear symbol.

Comment: Moreover, with an inexperienced (as in: still wobbly, concluded from "cannot take off right hand") biker, the flag with give a leveraged wobble that will alert drivers.

Answer (score 7):

To add to the other excellent answers:

### Be predictable, proactive, and be visible

I am a cyclist in a largish French city (Versailles), I also drive a car - and looking at cyclists from the perspective of a driver is what made me change my behaviour.

**Predictability:** make sure that what you do is expected by the drivers, even if it means thinking way ahead. You need to avoid a parking car? Start to deviate way before the car to make sure the car behind you understands what you want to do. Some will honk, does not matter - you made it alive.

**Visibility:** I look like a Christmas tree when I bike. Several lamps flash, I have reflective gear around. It looks really silly until the moment you realize that this is what made you visible to the car.

When you drive a car, you do not see everything. Some rain and you see 30% less. So always assume that the car does not see you until you see that they see - which means your eyes meet their eyes, or you see them stopping **for you**.

Comment: Being predictable is a lot about giving signals (early) and obeying the law.

Comment: @Michael: obeying the law is a good point. When you stop at a red light, the behaviour is expected by both the ones who drive on your lane (they know you will slow down), and especially the ones across.

Answer (score 4):

Answer: **Don't**.

People won't be more careful around you, but might feel an increased need to "educate" you (by honking at you when they think you shouldn't be in their way, for example).

Instead learn to cycle and be assertive and defensive, ask questions here, join a cycle club, etc.

As anecdotal evidence, a guy recently stopped his car, got out and physically attacked me while I was wearing a high-visibility vest. In a similar incident when I happened to be wearing a black wet suit including mask, the guy in the car didn't dare to get out and attack me.

In traffic, there is the rule of the strong. Don't show weakness.

Comment: Please tell me that "when I happened to be wearing a black wet suit including mask", you were riding a bike.

Comment: @DanieleProcida Of course - I was on my way home after a winter swim in a lake. Complete outfit of 5mm neoprene, only eyes showing. :)

Comment: That anecdote really doesn't prove anything. Somebody getting out of the car and physically attacking you clearly is an extreme outlier, regardless of your behaviour. There is no way to know whether that guy would also have attacked you if you'd been wearing black. If I were to guess, the only thing affecting the likelihood of such attacks is how “unreasonable” your behaviour seemed to the car driver, but I guess it was one of those drivers who think that driving a bicycle at all is _reasonability zero_ in the first place, so what you wear whilst doing it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Happens regularly around here. A cop advised me to stay off the road or, at some point, meet someone who beats me senseless with a bat. But obviously anecdotes never prove anything.

Comment: Which part of the world is this, just so that we can avoid it?

Comment: @ojs Downtown Zurich. The inhabitants are generally okay, but there are lots of out of towners who can't drive, aren't used to city traffic and have a pre-blown fuse after being stuck in traffic for half an hour (and potentially realizing that they should have taken the excellent public transport like a sane person). Traffic rarely moves faster than I cycle on average, but they insist on accelerating to 50km/h before they need to start braking for the next red light.

Comment: Instead of "strong" and "weakness" I'd see "confidence" as a better way of saying it.

Comment: @Nobody, A cop threatened to arrest me for commuting on a kick scooter in my own neighborhood. I was stopped at a stop sign and they pulled up behind me and rolled down the window.

Comment: Agreed. That is also my experience. It is much better to be as stealthy (invisible) as possible (and taking the necessary precautions - *never* assume to be seen in the dark, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I noticed something in your question that I want to address directly and I'm not sure if someone had already.

Riding a bicycle with long hair requires taking safety precautions. Please tie your hair up and away from any moving parts on the bicycle.

I rode bicycles for many years with my long hair and it does feel quite good. I think, as a general rule, when you're wearing a helmet and riding a bicycle the hair needs to be secured, just like if you're working around moving machinery.

Comment: This is a fair point and while it doesn't answer the title question, it does address a point in OP's text, that may not have occurred to them (though if one lives with long hair, one becomes aware of spinning things and alert to the risks imposed.)    BUT there's no correlation between long hair and inexperienced cyclists - Laurent Fignon is an example of that!

Comment: I hadn't thought about cycling with long hair since it's been so long since I cut mine.  But one thing to watch out for, when tying up your hair, is that it doesn't interfere with the fit of your helmet.  I favoured a braid for keeping mine from flying around, but had to start the braid fairly low - below the nape of the neck - in order for the helmet to fit properly.  (A hair band would have to be placed similarly low, but I found they in order for them to stay in place for hours of riding they had to be tight enough that fiddling with them to get the helmet to sit properly was annoying.)

Answer (score 3):

I ride in Paris a lot, and I'm often seen as inexperienced because I use a lot of shared bikes (Velib). I'll add that my personal criteria to judge a cyclist as inexperienced is their ability to keep a straight trajectory, so in my opinion that's the first thing you should work on, which includes indicating when you are about to change said trajectory.

In my experience, being seen as a newbie driver will make other drivers a bit more wary (they usually don't want to hit a cyclist) BUT will also make them angry, so it's up to you to make sure you want to display your inexperience.

One thing I find reassuring is to have a **side mirror** like [this one](https://www.decathlon.fr/p/retroviseur-de-velo-100/_/R-p-512). It shows to the drivers that you see them and will usually prompt them to use their turning signals more often when they pass you (since you can see it thanks to the mirror). You can also use some **dissuasive plastic clips** like [this one](https://www.lecyclo.com/velo/securite/signalisation/ecarteur-de-danger-pour-velo.html), but it might hinder you, your call.

If you happen to have a bad interaction with drivers, my take on it is to notice the honkings / angry rants and reflect on it. If you are genuinely doing something wrong (e.g. forgot to go back to the right lane) then correct it, maybe thank the driver with a hand / foot sign and that's it. If you are doing nothing wrong, just riding slowly for example, just ignore it, they are being the bad driver, not you. As many people said, some people honk learning drivers' cars, can't do much about it.

Comment: In my experience, a mirror is on bicycle is a surefire sign that the rider is about to do something sudden and stupid. Maybe it's because they believe they can see the traffic behind but actually don't, maybe because they see you and react by weaving around.

Comment: I see your point yes. But then if you know the rider in front of you is about to do something sudden, you'll be more careful, so I see that as a win :)
I obviously don't have one when I'm on a shared bike and I feel that when I'm just turning my head to look behind me, the drivers take that as a confirmation that I saw them and that they can now pass me even when they actually can't, be it because that was a glance before indicating that I'm about to turn, a narrow street, traffic incoming, whatever. Also happens with the mirror, but less frequently in my anecdotal experience.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who both drives and rides a bike, I'm a bit paranoid about being the cyclist in a car/cyclist collision. Thus, when riding, I try to (a) avoid the possibility of physically "interacting" with a car and (b) be highly visible.

Personally, I'd rather ride on the sidewalk (if legal in your area) or a car-free trail or low-traffic sidestreet even if that slows me down (my normal pace is about 14mph). I also wear multiple bright blinking red tail-lights, at least one on my bike and one on the back of my helmet.

It gets dark late these days in the northern hemisphere, but try to think about visibility from a driver's point of view. If you're young and have good vision, put on a pair of sunglasses at twilight, ride in a car or bus and see how much more difficult it is to spot riders then. Remember, there are plenty of drivers out there with much worse vision than you, and who are likely concentrating more on other cars or being late than looking out for cyclists.

Also, don't wear earpods/headphones while riding -- your sense of hearing can alert you to danger from the side or behind that you can't see. Good luck!

Comment: Sidewalks are not necessarily safer. Nobody expects cyclists on the sidewalk. Lots of people step out of their houses without looking (why would they?), on intersections you are hard to see (and don’t have right of way, even if you’d have it on the accompanying road) and driveways are a nightmare to safely cross.

Comment: +1 for the _no headphones_! Otherwise, I generally disagree with riding on the sidewalk/pavement, as well. It's generally illegal (unless it's a designated bike path).

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that when riding on the sidewalk, it's either in an area with essentially no pedestrians, or at a quite slow speed so as not to endanger others. The point is that everyone needs to choose their own tradeoff between speed, convenience and personal safety.

Answer (score 1):

- The go-to book in the UK is Cyclecraft by John Franklin.  ISBN 9780117037403
- You won't educate car drivers.  If you think ahead and avoid well-known traps then you should be fine.
- See and be seen.  (Keep about 1m from the curb. Space never killed anybody. You are entitled to be on the road.  If they honk that's fine -- It shows they've seen you.)
- Cycling safely is NOT intuitive: https://vulpeculox.net/cycling/qcktest.htm
- Key points on one page: https://vulpeculox.net/cycling/pedalpoints2.htm
- You will find some particular places very tricky/scary.  A simple strategy is 'avoid' but another is to be bold with a bit of help from a more experienced cyclist.
- Find a buddy.  (Ask at work.  Chat to fellow cyclists while stopped at the red light.) Even just 45 minutes with an experienced cyclist will free you from of a lot of habits you never knew were bad and help you claim your bit of space on the road.

Good luck and happy adventures.  You are not a victim!

Answer (score -2):

My recommendation would be to relax.

Do not excessively worry about drivers around you.

Just stay to the right of your bicycle lane like most laws specify.

I have seen riders not caring to stay to the right of the bicycle lane.

They are just asking to be hit.

Do NOT run stop signs or lights no matter how tempting it is.

When I am driving a car, I will go to the left lane to allow clearance for the bicycle rider.

But many drivers do not do so.

Take care,

Andy

Comment: If you ride to the right of the bicycle lane, you risk running into suddenly opened car doors from drivers/passengers who don't pay attention. It's less dangerous to ride on the car lane, as drivers coming from behind will definitely see you.

Comment: At least in Germany, you don't HAVE to ride on all bicycle lanes, only those marked with a white-and-blue sign. So by law, it's often very legal to ride on the car lane. And "not worrying" in traffic is delusional, perhaps unless you sit in a massive "city tank", i.e. SUV.